# Is It Possible to Know the Location of the Caller?

Tags: calls, geolocation

If I'm using an Android, is it possible to know the *physical*  location of the person who call me/ I call to?

Comment: yes if you're 911, there are laws all over the world restricting devices from broadcasting the owner's location information without their explicit permission, except for the emergency response services.

Comment: The emergency response authority does not have that feature in the EU IIRC, it was apparently bandied about in the media that they were going to implement it in 2015...and let's be honest here, as a individual average Joe User, why would you want to know the physical location of the caller?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. I have not tried the [WorldCallPlaceAndTime](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ru.atrant.worldcallplaceandtime) App but it looks like what you want. Below you can see the summary and screenshot from appbrain.

**EDIT:** Based on the comments on appbrain, this app just determines the caller's location based on the phone number's area code. If you want to know the phone's physical location, you'll need to use something like Google Latitude, which does not give you the caller's location during the call (yet).

> This program shows a small
>   CUSTOMIZABLE info window during
>   incoming/outgoing call: country,
>   region, city (or mobile operator) and
>   LOCAL TIME in that place (worldwide)!
>
> 2.0: colors option for donators, bugfixes
>
> tag: call location,calllocation,who's
>   calling,wer ruft an,caller id,who
>   called

[image]

Comment: I was going to say, the only way you'd know is by area code or public number listing.

Comment: This app flashes the info for half a second yes it technically meets the specification but is not particularly useful.  Do you know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only do a lookup for a house phone. A mobile phone you don't know where they are most likely unless you have a subopena.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Mobile Number & Phone Location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=and.p2l) form Google Play Store.

Comment: A brief description about the app and why  does the app is useful to question, both points are required in the answer. Consider adding them.

Answer (score 0):

[TrueCaller](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.trueCaller.trial) ($6.99) does area code lookups plus public directory lookups.  If the number is in a public directory it'll tell you the person's name & address (if available) otherwise it defaults to showing the location based on area code. I've never used it and it does not have very good reviews in the app market but it seems like a lot of those are from people with unrealistic expectations and people who don't want to pay for apps.

Comment: I was trying to get **TrueCaller** app and it says "This app is unfortunately no longer available on the Android market."

Comment: @swiftBoy updated link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller