# Is it possible to get caller location by GPS?

Tags: gps, gps-tracking

I know there is [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/is-it-possible-to-know-the-location-of-the-caller) about that but I don't have the ability to comment there and it's an old question. So, I need some update on the topic:

1. is it possible now to get a location of the mobile phone caller, at least city and country?
2. Let's say we have an app installed on both phones (being called and caller). Is it technically possible to share GPS location between these two within that app, so they can see the location of each other constantly, even when travelling?
   In other words, is it possible to send GPS location from one phone to the other?

Comment: For #1, Are you asking about for applications, or regular phone calls? Who is trying to find the location?

Comment: I rather think of creating an app that allows such functionality during the call, or so.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any mobile phone provider needs to be able to route calls to the correct tower to service a phone, so they must know to at least the location to the accuracy of the tower cell area. Generally speaking, this information is not available to parties in a telephone call.

   An application can read the location at any time, and gets this as latitude and longitude. It is up to you to do a lookup of the city and country from this information.
2. Yes. A phone application gets location information as latitude and longitude, and the applications can simply exchange these values as strings over the data network.